# WCF Web Service causing browser to crash when using Jquery.ajax wihen data return is ~35k

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using jquery .ajax() to call a WCFweb service. When I call the web services sometimes my browser crash. The code behind the WCF is working and it complies my output. The output is a string. The string in the case where it crash is 36236 chars long. It has a size of 35.3k. I don't think it is a timeout issue as I get the error message nearly instantaneously. When less data is returned it works. What could be wrong?

The error message I am getting is:

[image]

The js code is as follows

```
 try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/_vti_bin/ab/WCFAB.svc/GetDetails',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: myid,
            success: function (msg) {
                wcfServiceGetSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: wcfServiceGetFailed
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert('error invoking service.get()' + e);
    }
```

**Update**

If I limit the number of results returned it works. So it looks to be a data size issue on the returned amount.

Answer (score 0):

Any crash message you are getting ?

Can you check the service is not crashing for some reason. Replace your ajax call with a simple call and see if it work.

Can you post your code here? SO that we can see the way you are calling your service.

Answer (score 0):

The string returned was html tags. There was an error in the tags. When 100 results was returned with the error the browser could cope with it. When there was a large number of errors the browser broke. Fixing the error in the html syntax meant that the brwoser rendered the page corrtectley